# LLDB convenience variable object assignment is nil?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Ran into this phenomenon while debugging something else and am curious:

```
(lldb) po (NSException *)($eax)
$3 = 0x0d16c510 Test exception message
(lldb) expr NSException *$exception = (NSException *)($eax)
(lldb) po $exception
$exception = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

I'm running an iOS app in the 6.1 Simulator.  Why would assigning a convenience variable give me nil when referencing $eax directly gives me an object?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this with Xcode 4.6.2 but could not.  I created a template iOS app and launched it in the simulator.  I didn't bother getting to a place where I had an exception in a register - I but the register value is the important thing here.

```
(lldb) reg read eax
     eax = 0x10004005
(lldb) p (NSException*) ($eax)
(NSException *) $0 = 0x10004005 <not an Objective-C object>
(lldb) expr NSException*$exception = (NSException *)($eax)
(lldb) p $exception
(NSException *) $exception = 0x10004005 <not an Objective-C object>
(lldb)
```

In your example `$exception` had a value of 0x0 but when I tried this with 4.6.2, it looks like it is working.  What version of Xcode were you using?

Comment: Very strange - I'm also using Xcode 4.6.2 (4H1003).  Let me try reproducing it in a clean project this evening and seeing if it still breaks.